Keeping underlined term in table of contents
In a Microsoft Word document, one of the headings has a specific word that must be underlined (and a different one must be italicized) every time it is present, and is formatted that way in the header within the document.
Is it possible to use the automated table of contents generator and still maintain the distinct formatting of that term in the table of contents?

If you don't need the ToC to be hyperlinked (i.e. probably it's only for printing), then remove the hyperlinking (e.g. remove the \h from the field code) My guess is that you do need it to be hyperlinked, but you don't say.

The problem with the Table of Contents is that it is a bunch of hyperlinks.  By default, hyperlinks are underlined and blue.  Automated Table of Contents sets the font to one that

Removes the underline (regardless of whether or not there was one)
Changes the colour to black

It is only the underline variants (single, double, bold, dotted, dashed) that won't work.  All other font enhancements like bold, italic, strike through, double strike through, superscript and subscript will work.  Is it possible to change your title to one of these font enhancements?
A totally crap workaround is to insert the underlined item in an inline frameless textbox but the table of contents will show it in the original font size: not the size of the font of the table of contents.
